# Validate IP Address in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am looking for a way to validate ip adrress field (onChange) in my RN mobile app.

But it's taking both valid and invalid ip addresses and also number of digits in each part remains exact three.

[image: Screenshot of App]

I am using `react-native-mask-input` and so far I have tried this:

```
const ipMask = [
    [/\d/],
    [/\d/],
    [/\d/],
    '.',
    [/\d/],
    [/\d/],
    [/\d/],
    '.',
    [/\d/],
    [/\d/],
    [/\d/],
    '.',
    [/\d/],
    [/\d/],
    [/\d/],
  ];

<View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
        <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column'}}>
          <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
            <Text
              style={{
                fontFamily: 'Titillium-Semibold',
                color: Colors.grey_888888,
                fontSize: 14,
                marginLeft: 13,
              }}>
              IP Address *
            </Text>
          </View>
          <MaskInput
            value={ip}
            mask={ipMask}
            style={{
              marginLeft: 10,
              marginRight: 10,
              marginTop: 5,
              fontSize: 15,
              width: '95%',
              fontFamily: 'Titillium-Semibold',
              fontWeight: 'normal',
              paddingBottom: 0,
              height: 50,
              backgroundColor: '#FAFAFA',
              borderColor: Colors.grey_C0C0C0,
              borderWidth: 1,
              borderRadius: 5,
            }}
            onChangeText={(masked, unmasked, obfuscated) => {
              setIP(masked);
            }}
          />
          <Text
            style={{
              fontFamily: 'Titillium-Semibold',
              color: Colors.red_FF0000,
              fontSize: 11,
              marginLeft: 10,
            }}>
            {requiredMsg.ip && 'IP address is required !!!'}
          </Text>
        </View>
      </View>
```

Can anyone suggest me a way to validate ip address correctly?

Comment: may be this will help you "npm i is-ip"

Answer (score 0):

Get the `is-ip` package from NPM. The link [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/is-ip) can be helpful.

Then, you can simply use the functions to check. E.g:

```
isIP('192.168.0.1'); // returns true
```

You'll find more code sample in the webpage above.

EDIT: I just noticed the date of the question... :')